# FromResource not returning image from project folder

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm currently learning Xamarin and I get figure out why the ResourceId isn't returning the image in my project. I just get a blank page. App.xaml.cs has MainPage set to the ImagePage.XAML below so that's not the issue. I made the resource ID set to the path of folders, but nothing.

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld.MarkupExtensions;assembly=HelloWorld.Android"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.ImagePage">

<!--
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning ="{Binding Source={x:Reference Image}, Path=IsLoading}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 100, 100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"  Color="#428bca" />
-->
        <Image x:Name="Image" Aspect="AspectFill"/>


</ContentPage>
```

XAML.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ImagePage : ContentPage
    {
        public ImagePage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

          Image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("HelloWorld.Images.background.jpg");

        }


    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ### Local Images
>
> Image files can be added to each application project and referenced from Xamarin.Forms shared code. To use a single image across all apps, *the same filename must be used on every platform*, and it should be a valid Android resource name (ie. only lowercase letters, numerals, the underscore, and the period are allowed).

[Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Local_Images) you have the official documentation explaining how to use local Images in Xamarin Forms.

***Edit***

Did you forgot the dot between Images and Background. HelloWorld.Images.background.jpg instead of HelloWorld.Imagesbackground.jpg ?

Comment: I fixed the period, but same issue. I've reviewed the documentation and I am doing the same thing as that site says. I have the image and I set it to EmbbededResource and I point to the path like in the example. What else could be the issue?\

Comment: Where are the .droid and .ios projects in your solution explorer ?